# How to see the preview of an HTML file logged to the console in Firefox DevTools?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

In Firebug's console you used to be able to expand a logged network request to see the request and reponse info.

Under the *Response* tab you had the option to see the response as raw data or as HTML. The HTML preview was handy, because if the response contained an error, it was easier to read what the error was without seeing a ton of HTML markup.

The console in the Firefox DevTools also shows you the request and response data, but under *Response* only the raw data is shown.

Is there a way to see the response as HTML preview like in Firebug?

PS: So far the only way I can see the HTML preview is to paste the markup into a file and open it in a browser, which works but is slower than just being able to view in the developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requests logged to the console don't provide that feature, but if you click on the URL of the logged request, you switch to the [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor), which has a *Preview* side panel.

[image: Preview in Network Monitor]

Furthermore, there's already a [request for adding the preview also to the Web Console](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1247392).

Comment: I couldn't find the preview at first because it was set to headers. This is exactly what I have been looking for. Thanks. I hope they add this functionality soon, because I have been so used to it in firebug. Thanks for editing my post. I had trouble laying out the information clearly.

Comment: Happy I could help! I am already [pushing on fixing all the gaps between Firebug and the DevTools](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=991806#c14). As this issue has an easy workaround (and the Network Monitor is generally the better tool when inspecting network requests), I assume it has lower priority than other missing Firebug features, though.

Comment: @SebastianZartner I cannot find the Preview panel on Network tab...is it removed? I have mozilla v55.0.3

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the panel got [removed in Firefox 55](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1350229) due to the incorrect assumption that it duplicated funcionality. Somebody is currently working on adding a [new preview within the *Response* panel](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1353319).